# sql browser, if it's disabled I can see my default instance in Network Servers?

Tags: sql-server

Hi
  I have sql server 2008 and an express version which was installed as part of Visual Studio.
I want to see the 2008 version in the network servers of SQL Server Management Studio.

If the SQL browser service is disabled I can see my 2008 instance listed. If it's enabled
I only see the sql express version?

Either way I can't see the 2008 version from other machines

Any ideas?

Thanks

p.s.
Firewall is off locally

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why one shows up locally when the browser server is disabled and the other when it is enabled, but as far as seeing them on other machines make sure UDP port 1434 is open on any firewall software you are running locally as the SQL Browser service uses that port.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx
>
> "Upon startup, SQL Server Browser
>   starts and claims UDP port 1434. SQL
>   Server Browser reads the registry,
>   identifies all instances of SQL Server
>   on the computer, and notes the ports
>   and named pipes that they use. When a
>   server has two or more network cards,
>   SQL Server Browser returns the first
>   enabled port it encounters for SQL
>   Server. SQL Server Browser support
>   ipv6 and ipv4."

Unless it has changed recently, by default, SQL Express does not listen for remote requests (on the network), just locally. But, that can be changed if needed.